# Differences between 碁 and 囲碁

Tags: word-choice, usage

Both 碁{ご} and 囲碁{いご} mean the game Go according to my dictionary. Is one of the terms more common than the other or used in different kinds of situations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

碁 and 囲碁 refer to exactly the same game, and they are interchangeable. Both are safely understood by all native speakers, but 囲碁 is more common presumably because 碁 is too short.

In kanji compounds 碁 and 囲碁 are not interchangeable. 碁石 is always 碁石, not 囲碁石.